# Pagination in Desc or Asc Order in CI 4

Tags: php, pagination, codeigniter-4

I am working on CI 4 pagination. Pagination is working fine and by defaults it returns results in `asc` order.

Here is my code i am using in controller like this.

```
$data['blog_posts'] = $this->blogsModel->paginate('10');
```

**Problem**

**How can i get data in `DESC` order in CI 4?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CI4, you can use the following :

```
$this->model->orderBy($sort_key, $sort_value);
```

Also note, orderBy will be before the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$data['blog_posts'] = $this->blogsModel->order_by("column_name", "desc")->paginate('10');
```

Comment: `Call to undefined method App\Models\BlogsModel::order_by`

Comment: @HamzaZafeer take a look here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide4/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results